# How do I create a canvas element in Dart?

Tags: html, canvas, dart

I want to create a canvas element that I can add to an html document.  The Dart recommendations seem to be to use `dart:html` rather then `dart:dom`, but as far as I can see, `dart:html` only contains an interface definition for a `CanvasElement` interface, not a class.

How do I instantiate a canvas object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eventually you'll be able to just do:

```
new CanvasElement();
```

The new HTML lib hasn't been fully populated with constructors yet, though. It's a work-in-progress. In the meantime, the easiest way is probably:

```
new Element.html('<canvas></canvas>');
```

That will return an instance of `CanvasElement`.

Comment: Also possible is `new Element.tag('canvas')`

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, you can create objects directly from an interface (http://www.dartlang.org/docs/getting-started/interface.html) so there is nothing wrong to create canvas using `new CanvasElement()`.

Comment: As munificent mentioned, this is not true in many places at this stage. new CanvasElement() doesn't work right now.